# Apache Ignite server node health check

Tags: ignite

I am working on launching an Apache Ignite (v2.13.0) cluster in AWS. I am targeting using Amazon ECS for container management and running these container nodes on EC2 instances.

I am fronting these instances with an Application Load Balancer and using the Apache Ignite `aws-ext` modules [TcpDiscoverALBIpFinder](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/blob/master/modules/aws-ext/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/elb/TcpDiscoveryAlbIpFinder.java) to find other nodes in the cluster. As part of setting up an ALB in AWS, you add a [listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html) that routes traffic to a registered healthy target. These targets are represented by a [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html). These nodes in the target group are tested periodically to check their health via a [health check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html). The health check sends a request to a configured port and path and determines the health based on returned status codes.

My question is if there is an out of the box path on an Apache Ignite server that I should utilize for health checks?

I looked for additional documentation online on how others have set this up however came up dry.

Cheers!

Comment: Were you able to get this cluster working in ECS & ALB? When we looked at this it seems Ignite is now focused on EKS deployments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the PROBE/VERSION commands to implement these checks.

example usage: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/restapi#probe

Comment: Thank you Alex this is perfect! The probe command wasn't in the Apache Ignite docs I was utilizing: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi

Answer (score 1):

Most people use the [REST API](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi#version) for health checks.

Comment: Understood, I got thrown off by the fact that the version command had an error attribute in the response. The PROBE command that Alex K answered will be what we utilize. Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 1):

readinessProbe:

- with auth: http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=probe&ignite.login=ignite&ignite.password=ignite
- without auth: http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=probe

livenessProbe:

- with auth: http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version&ignite.login=ignite&ignite.password=ignite
- without auth: http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version